# Center sweetalert text with css

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

I'm trying to center text in my swal-box, but it wont work:

CSS3:

```
.swal-modal {
    text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
swal("myTitle", "some text \n some more text \n even more text);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Adding an `!important` statement right behind `center` might work.

Comment: what version of sweetalert are you using?

Comment: I am using
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can center the text with css in swal-modal

```
.swal-modal .swal-text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can apply a custom style to the default sweet alert class

```
swal-text {
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Align sweetalert text:**

```
.swal2-html-container {
  text-align: justify !important;
}
```